# Wordpress send XML file to email

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to achieve this result: I'm using contact form 7 and I want that when you click on "Submit", you don't receive the email in plaintext, but an .xml file containing all the information.
As a workaround for the xml file I'm using that function:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_send' );

function CF7_pre_send($cf7) {
   $output = "";
   $output .= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>Name: " . $_POST['your-name'];
   $output .= "Email: " . $_POST['your-email'];
 $output .= "Message: " . $_POST['your-message'];

 file_put_contents("cf7outputtest.xml", $output);
}
```

So that's generates the xml file but I'm able to save it only in the wordpress directory, or in a specific path. Is there a way or a workaround to send this xml directly to an email address?

Thanks in advance,

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After it has generated the file, the function can send it using the `wp_mail` function.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'CF7_pre_send' );

function CF7_pre_send($cf7) {
   $output = "";
   $output .= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>Name: " . $_POST['your-name'];
   $output .= "Email: " . $_POST['your-email'];
 $output .= "Message: " . $_POST['your-message'];

 file_put_contents( "cf7outputtest.xml", $output);

   // then send email
   $to = "sendto@example.com";
   $subject = "The subject";
   $body = "The email body content";
   $headers = "From: My Name <myname@example.com>" . "\r\n";

   $attachments = array( "cf7outputtest.xml" );

   wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments );
}
```